# toilet floor bolt spins in flange

Tags: toilet

My toilet is currently off the floor. I have a new toilet ready to go in.  The existing floor flange is in ok shape, minimal to no rust, with the Everbuilt wax ring + bolt package.

The bolt will on one side of the flange work and not spin, but on the other side for whatever is happening it does not lock and not spin. I am not pulling and replacing the floor flange, as it otherwise doesn't need to be.

What is a good way to get the toilet floor bolt to lock in to the flange and not spin, but be serviceable in the future?  Do I need to find a better [bolt](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-5-16-in-x-3-1-2-in-Heavy-Duty-Toilet-Bowl-to-Floor-Bolt-Set-1000055110/312258757)?

Comment: Does the bolt spin if it is pulled up all the way?  Problem is probably the frange, either the lock slot is worn or the bolt is falling out.

Comment: looking for ideas how do I make the existing flange work on that one side

Comment: The best way is to take the flange off and see what the problem is.  Something like dental picks might let you feel around and maybe dig out stuff.  They will not work if the problem is a worn out slot.

Comment: Might be able to hotglue it in place enough to get the bolt steady enough so that the by the time the nut starts compressing there's enough friction to keep it from free-spinning. It can be un-done later by a heat gun.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the situation, here are some suggestions.

Is the bolt compatible with the flange? Your flange may need a bolt more like a carriage bolt, with an integrated block.

Is the bolt prevented from engaging with the slot due to misalignment, debris, or damage? Does it need to be *lifted* to engage the slot?

Is the bolt head positioned in the flange slot and not at the bolt key entrance?

Comment: I have 2 bolts, identical, one works on one side of the flange but the other side it spins.  So I have to believe the bolts are compatible with the flange, and the however the flange is formed is either bent or rusted on the one side where I can't see and letting the bolt head spin.

Comment: Well there you go. :) That's not something we can help with from here, though.

Answer (score 1):

Fold sheet metal shims (flashing, or beer can metal) over the oval bolt head until it is fat enough to wedge in the flange slot, or bring the tails of the shims up through the slot and flatten them so that it grabs the slot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the different bolt sets you link to are acceptable for use, because they are made, in total or in part, of steel or other non-corrosion-resistant materials. The so-called "brass plating", or simply gold-colored finish on steel bolts will eventually corrode into a solid lump of rust, and cause great difficulties in removing the toilet in the future. The same goes for any nuts and washers. Solid brass toilet bolt sets are readily available, and such are required by many plumbing codes.

The problem of the bolt heads being too small (not likely with a genuine 5/16" brass set) can be overcome by using a thin (brass!) locknut tightened down to the flange - this would of course require 100% threaded bolts.

Comment: you mean the *Ever* part of Everbuilt doesn't apply to the included bolts?  home depot burned me they're selling junk toilet bolts?